# transformar formato serial a formato fecha en power query

Tags: excel, date, powerbi, powerquery

estoy haciendo una limpieza de datos en power query para usar en bi, y el formato de la fecha de las más de 14mil líneas de información está configurada en número serial, ejemplo: El número 44896 en el contexto de Excel representa la fecha del 3 de febrero de 2025
Ya he aplicado funciones, he creado columnas personalizadas, de todo y aún me sigue saliendo en error esa columna, alguien antes lo ha solucionado? no he encontrado algo en internet que me guíe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usando esta fórmula en una columna personalizada:

```
= Date.From(Number.From([columna_fecha]))
```

La columna fuente puede tener el tipo de dato 'Cualquiera' o también de 'Número' y debería funcionarte.

Suerte.